# Deleting Elements from Vectors in C++

Tags: c++

I'm coding a program based on a soccer team roster. Each player has a jersey number and rating. I'm trying to figure out how to delete a player's rating and jersey number if the user enter's said player's jersey number. I have two int vectors defined, one for the players jersey number and another for the players rating. This is what I have so far for my delete player function. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
void delete_player()
    {
        int input;
        int vecSize = jersey.size();
        cout << "Enter a jersey number to delete: ";
        cin >> input;
        for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
        {
            if (input == jersey[i])
            {
                jersey.erase(jersey.begin() + i);
                rating.erase(rating.begin() + i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using the wrong tool for the job. It seems like what you need is a `std::map<jerseyNum, rating>`. Something like this:

```
 using jerseyNum = int;
 using rating = int;
 using playerMap = std::map<jerseyNum, rating>;
 playerMap Players;
```

Then  you can add players to it by  doing something like this:

```
Players [ newJerseyNum ] = newRating;
```

You can delete players by doing this:

```
auto foundPlayer = Players.find(jerseyToDelete);
if (foundPlayer != Players.end())
{
     Players.erase(foundPlayer);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new to C++ programming and I'm unfamiliar with how to implement your suggestion. For my add player function I simply added each jersey number and rating to their respective vector using rating/jersey.push_back(input). Is there a simpler way for a beginner to remove a specific instance of an element within a vector using vector.erase?

Comment: @AlexCPSC A map uses an input to uniquely determine the output. If you write `Players[32] = "John"` and then `print( Players[32] )` to the screen, you will see "John" print to the console. The "key" 32 uniquely corresponds to the "value" John.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to write a loop to erase an item from a vector.  Use the `erase/remove` idiom:

```
void delete_player()
{
    int input;
    cout << "Enter a jersey number to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    jersey.erase(std::remove(std::begin(jersey), std::end(jersey), input), jersey.end());
    rating.erase(std::remove(std::begin(rating), std::end(rating), input), rating.end());
}
```

Basically, the [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) function will return an iterator to the "dead" items that are to be removed (at the end of the vector).  Then calling `vector::erase` starting from this iterator until `vector::end()` removes these dead items.

In general, if you find yourself writing loops or "hand-rolled" code that is doing a job that seems like it has been done many times before (such as removing items from a container), there is probably an STL algorithm or series of STL algorithm functions that do the job.  In this case `std::remove` is the algorithm function.

---

If what you need to do is to remove the corresponding `rating`, then you should use `std::find`:

```
void delete_player()
{
    int input;
    cout << "Enter a jersey number to delete: ";
    cin >> input;
    auto iter = std::find(std::begin(jersey), std::end(jersey), input);
    if (iter != std::end(jersey))
    {
       auto dist = std::distance(std::begin(jersey), iter);
       jersey.erase(std::begin(jersey) + dist);
       rating.erase(std::begin(rating) + dist);
    }
}
```

The `std::distance` simply returns the "distance" from the `begin()` to the iterator returned by `std::find`.

But there is a danger of implementing two separate vectors and handling them like this.  If `jersey` and `rating` are not the same size, you risk an out-of-bounds access when erasing from the `rating` vector.  The other answer given that shows usage of `std::map` is a much more appropriate container to use.

Comment: Solid advise and wisdom.

Comment: Doing this wouldn't work because the user has to enter the jersey number as input and delete the element in the vector with that jersey number and the corresponding element from the rating vector. So if a player had for example the jersey number 12 and a rating of 5 and i entered 12 into the console, the corresponding rating wouldn't be removed from the rating vector.

Comment: @AlexCPSC Then the other answer really is what you should be using ( a `std::map`).   See my edit if you have to use `vector`.  Also, `std::vector` being used in the way you're using it is error-prone, since you need to ensure that `jersey` and the `rating` vector are the same size.